# for文で得た結果を配列に入れたい

Tags: python

本当に簡単な質問で申し訳ありません。

```
def date():
  for num in range(0,100):
      num += 1
      print(num)
```

この結果（1から100まで全ての結果）を配列に入れたい場合はどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

これでどうでしょう

```
def date():
  result = []  # 結果を入れるリストを用意
  for num in range(0,100):
      num += 1
      print(num)
      result.append(num)  # 結果を追加
  return result  # 結果のリストを返す
```

Comment: for文で回している際に、配列に足していけばよいのですね。for文の中身はもう少し複雑なことをする予定なのですが、Takayuki SHIMIZUKAWAさんの回答で応用できそうです。

Answer (score 0):

`print()`がなくてよければ、リスト内包表記を使ってこういう書き方もできます

```
def date():
  return [x+1 for x in range(0, 100)]
```